# Tango3DR_textureMeshFromDataset not working after newest tango core update

Tags: google-project-tango

After a new tango core update (version 1.48:2016.....:unstable) that my Lenovo Phab2Pro auto updated today, the Tango3DR_textureMeshFromDataset function is not working anymore, with an error code of -3 (It worked fine with the last tango core version)

In the logcat output I get the following message:

```
mesh_painter_adapter.cc:85 Source camera not available; source_camera_=16 available_cameras_mask=4096
```

Anyone know how to fix this? Do I need to change some permissions or something?

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was to change the `config_dataset_recording_mode`.
Previously, setting the mode to `TANGO_RECORDING_MODE_SCENE_RECONSTRUCTION` 
was sufficient to do reconstruction with textured meshes. With the caporales update, it seems that it is required to set the mode to `TANGO_RECORDING_MODE_ALL` for getting the textured 3d reconstruction to work.